# Android background task with main class

Tags: java, android

I've run in to one little problem while working with the android API, this is it:

Is possible to make a BACKGROUND TASK (always running like a alarmtimer) that can read from common settings, I have problems with this since the main task gets unloaded when the app is closed (task keeps running but all the commands return null)

Is it even possible? if so, how?

Even more important, in my main class i have `SyncMaster = new SyncMaster(this);` and is there a way to talk to it via my background task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using BroadCast receiver that listens to system components and notifiy your MainClass

Comment: Sounds good and certainly will try it but how do i notify the mainclass when it is not loaded? all references return a nullpointerexception whilst in background

Comment: Do you want to launch mainClass on the event or just notify the application about the event?

Comment: Both would do, as long i can get data from and to the broadcast receiver its all good

Comment: If you want to notify activity when it is in the foreground, register you BroadCast receiver inside of the activity. Else if it is in background, register a reciever that could start a service and perform action needed and then launch Main activity from service.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

may be you should consider using a Service.

Comment: I tried using a serice but it does not allways run and when it does the main class gets unloaded, or at least returns NULL